# why aren't my bash aliases applied when logging in to server

Tags: bash, login, bashrc

When I log in to my Ubuntu 12.04 LTS server my bash aliases aren't applied, but if I execute `bash` from the command line they are.

`~/.profile` executes `~/.bashrc`:

```
if [ "$BASH" ]; then
  if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
    . ~/.bashrc
  fi
fi
```

, which in turn executes `~/.bash_aliases`:

```
if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    . ~/.bash_aliases
fi
```

and `ps -p $$` shows

`31662 pts/0    00:00:00 bash`

Do I have something misconfigured?

Answer (score 4):

So the problem was that I had both a `~/.profile` and `~/.bash_profile`, and `~/.bash_profile` (which was added to the system when I installed RVM, which explains why it worked and then stopped working) did not execute `~/.bashrc`.

Bash's [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash) explains that `~/.bash_profile` is checked before `~/.profile`, and if it exists, `~/.profile` is not executed.