# `alias` command in `.profile` not recognized until `source .profile` is called

Tags: alias, .profile

I have the following line in my `.profile` file in my home directory:

`alias flux='redshift -O 2500'`

But whenever I login and type `flux` I get a `flux is not a recognized command`.

I then do a `source .profile` and type `flux` again and it works perfectly.

I am on Ubuntu 20.04

Why is the `alias` in my `.profile` not working unless I do a `source .profile`?

edit: I understand now that `.profile` is not the correct place to put this.

I ended up loading aliases from the `.bashrc` file using the `source` command:

```
for file in ~/.dotfiles/.{exports,aliases}; do
    [ -r "$file" ] && source "$file"
done
unset file
```

Comment: Try to move that line to a `~/.bash_aliases` file.

Comment: Do you have `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.bash_login`?

Comment: Related: [How do I create a permanent Bash alias?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17536/how-do-i-create-a-permanent-bash-alias) This is arguably a duplicate of that, though I'm *somewhat* inclined to think not, since it doesn't address what happens with alias definitions in `~/.profile` and why that file is not suitable for them.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*TL;DR:* **As [Gunnar Hjalmarsson says](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1256575/alias-command-in-profile-not-recognized-until-source-profile-is-called/1256577#comment2123266_1256575), put aliases in `~/.bash_aliases`.**

The commands in `~/.profile` are run by login shells. That file is a good place to do things that should be done once at the beginning of each session but not repeated every time a new shell is started. `~/.profile` is good for setting environment variables, which will be inherited by all descendant processes.

Aliases are not inherited, and the shell you get in a terminal window in Ubuntu is not (by default) a login shell. To define aliases for all your interactive Bash shells, the definitions need to be somewhere where they'll be run each time you start such a shell.

The usual places are either in:

- `~/.bashrc`
- `~/.bash_aliases`

New interactive non-login shells source `~/.bashrc` (as do some noninteractive shells). Your `~/.profile`, by default, sources `~/.bashrc`.

The default `~/.bashrc` in Ubuntu checks if `~/.bash_aliases` exists and sources it.

I recommend putting new aliases in `~/.bash_aliases`.

---

Sourcing `~/.profile` works to define the aliases, but it also re-runs everything else in that file, most of which you don't need to run again, and some of which might do things you don't want. For example, `~/.profile` checks if `~/bin` exists and, if so, prepends it to your `$PATH`. If you source `~/.profile` multiple times, you can get the same directory appearing multiple times in `$PATH`. This would have to happen quite a lot to cause a significant performance problem. But even one extra occurrence can cause confusion when you're inspecting the output of a command like `printenv PATH`.

If your aliases aren't defined *even in initial login shells*, such as when you log in from a virtual console or via SSH, then as [Kulfy alludes to](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1256575/alias-command-in-profile-not-recognized-until-source-profile-is-called/1256577#comment2123270_1256575) the issue may be that you have a `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.bash_login` file. [If such a file exists, Bash login shells source it instead of `~/.profile`.](https://askubuntu.com/a/204671/22949) Most often you would not want to have either such file on Ubuntu, and if you did, you would most likely want it to source `~/.profile` so that the commands in `~/.profile` still run.

But even if that is the case, you shouldn't define aliases in `~/.profile` (nor in `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.bash_login`), as that doesn't define them in non-login shells.